# Replacing text in multiple files-getting duplicate error

Tags: powershell, shell-script

I want to loop through all files (2 for this test) in current folder and replace text.

The replacement is working but I'm left with newfile1 and newfile2 in file1 and the same in file 2. Where I just want newfile 1 in file 1 and newfile 2 in file 2.

Assuming my ForEach-Object is in the wrong spot but cant fix it. Any suggestions?

```
@echo off
call:DoReplace "a1" "a2" *.txt "a3" "a4" 
exit /b

:DoReplace
echo ^(Get-Content "%3"^) ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace %1, %2 -replace %4, %5} ^| Set-Content %3>Rep.ps1 
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy ByPass -File Rep.ps1
if exist Rep.ps1 del Rep.ps1
echo Done
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty, but it works:

```
Get-ChildItem \\path\to\folder -Filter '*.txt' | foreach {
$text = Get-Content $_.FullName
$text = $text -replace 'a2','test'
$text = $text -replace 'a4','foo'
$text | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

The problem with your script is that you need to `Set-Content` in the `ForEach-Object` loop.

Comment: Fixed it using the following. Thanks.                                                       @echo off

call:DoReplace "a1" "a2" *.txt a3" "a4"
exit /b

:DoReplace
for /r %%i in (%3) do (
 echo Processing: %%i
 echo ^(Get-Content "%%i"^) ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace %1, %2  -replace %4, %5} ^| Set-Content "%%i">Rep.ps1 
 Powershell.exe -executionpolicy ByPass -File Rep.ps1
 if exist Rep.ps1 del Rep.ps1
)
echo Done
pause